# Install The Wkhtmltopdf Extension issue in Odoo 15 Packaged By Bitnami

Tags: odoo, wkhtmltopdf, bitnami, vmware-workstation, odoo-15

**Install The Wkhtmltopdf Extension issue in Odoo 15 Packaged By Bitnami For Windows / Linux / MacOS / OS X VM**

I got this error when using odoo 15 on VMware workstation 16

[Error / issue image | screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5vMF.png)

this is what the error shows in my odoo web interf

```
Report 

Unable to find Wkhtmltopdf on this system. 
The report will be shown in html.<br><br><a
 href="http://wkhtmltopdf.org/"
 target="_blank">wkhtmltopdf.org</a>
```

anyone can help with this isse ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same error when using odoo 15 on VMware workstation 16 pro

to be specific :

```
bitnami_odoo-15.0.202111010-0-linux-debian-10-x86_64-nami - VMware Workstation
```

Issue when you try to print the pdf :

[image: wkhtmltopdf issue bitnami odoo 15]

```
Report 

Unable to find Wkhtmltopdf on this system. 
The report will be shown in html.<br><br><a
 href="http://wkhtmltopdf.org/"
 target="_blank">wkhtmltopdf.org</a>
```

---

(If you didn't try the documentation method , I think that you should try it first ) 
If you are following the [Bitnami by VMware Documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/odoo/configuration/install-wkhtmltopdf/)   and it didn't work for you , like in my case then ...

first , start your odoo 15 on your vm and login :

[image: use the following command after you login : sudo -s]

Follow these tutorials all of them worked well for me :

- 1. https://community.bitnami.com/t/wkhtmltopdf-not-installing/51686
- 2. https://github.com/odoo/technical-training/blob/d21cc5ca28157b36c9c5a9ea5c899b38286a7e97/99-sysadmin/README.md#wkhtmltopdf

**WKHtmlToPdf 

To print reports, odoo generates an html, send it to wkhtmltopdf which is in charge of the html->pdf transformation.**

```
$ sudo apt install libxrender1 fontconfig
$ wget http://nightly.odoo.com/deb/xenial/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
$ wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

[image]

- 3. https://webkul.com/blog/installing-odoo-on-ubuntu/

> Step 6: Installing Wkhtmltopdf
> Odoo uses wkhtmltopdf to convert the html reports into pdf format. But all the versions of wkhtmltopdf does not support odoo. Here is the process to install the supported version for a system with 64 bit architecture. First download the package for installation:

```
wget http://download.gna.org/wkhtmltopdf/0.12/0.12.1/wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb
```

> Once the package is downloaded install it and copy the files accordingly:

```
dpkg -i wkhtmltox-0.12.1_linux-trusty-amd64.deb


sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
sudo cp /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage /usr/bin
```

***when you are done , restart your vm and it should work*** ✅✅

Answer (score 0):

Odoo 16, Ubuntu 22.04 jammy

1. `apt install wkhtmltopdf`
2. `systemctl restart odoo`  # causes about 4 seconds of downtime here

Now it works for me. [Odoo's wiki](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/wiki/Wkhtmltopdf) says something about headers and footers not being supported, but the packages are far out of date and it can't be installed on an Ubuntu system released more than a year ago, and the repository version seemed to work (still waiting on feedback from our users though, maybe I overlooked a footer they configured)